# How do I determine if a file of a certain name exists in my iOS document directory

Tags: ios, caching, path

I'm trying to download and cache data in iPhone document directory. I would like to be able to check to see if a file exists and populate my UITableViewCell with the local data if it exists, and load the data remotely if it does not.

Here is the code I am using to download the data.

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"The Error Is: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: NSFileManager has a method to see if a file exists at a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *pathToMyFile = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDataFile"];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToMyFile]) {
    // file exists
}
else {
    // file doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the documents directory right? Use this code:

```
NSString* documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FILENAME"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    // file exists
}
else {
    // file doesn't exist
}
```

Note: You might want to check if AFNetworking creates a directory in the document path for storing anything it downloads. These libraries usually create their own directories.